# Assign CSV values to variables

Tags: php, variables, csv

I would like the following code to assign a variable to each value read from my CSV file.

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

So for example, inside the CSV file I have 4 values from 2 Excel columns:

```
Jack,31/01/1991
Ross,15/03/1989
```

And I would like the make Jack variable `$vrble1`, 31/01/1991 `$vrble2`, Ross `$vrble3` and 15/03/1989 `$vrble4`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use array for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per each iteration you merge the data into a single array:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("test.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$data = call_user_func_array('array_merge', iterator_to_array($file));
```

And then you can extract the array data into the local varialbles like this:

```
$data = array_combine(range(1, count($data)), $data);
extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'vrble');
```

See [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) and [`extract`](http://php.net/extract).

However you should continue using arrays if you ask me.

Comment: OK, thanks! I see what I did wrong now. I was wondering, how can I display the first entry in the array? data[0]?

Comment: Yes, `$data[0]` should be the first entry, if that does not work, try `$data[1]`. Do a `var_dump($data);` to see what's on.

Comment: Yeah $data[1] works! You solved all my problems. Thank you a lot. I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to do that but i think that you can do it (if i didn't get it wrong) with:

```
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
  $vname = 'vrble' . ($c+1);
  $$vname = $data[$c];
}
```

With that, you have the values in variables like $vrble1, $vrble2.

Let me know if this answer your question.

Comment: I'm afraid not, the fgetcsv splits the values from de row, so in data you have array ( col1, col2). Now i'm not sure and i can't test it

Comment: This works. But it will only show me the first two values in the CSV file. (e.g. Jack,31/01/1991 but not Ross...). So basically $vrble1 is Jack and $vrble2 is 31/01/1991 but if I use $vrble3 I get an error saying: Undefined variable: vrble3

Comment: True. You could use another counter instead of $c. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

just a small edit

```
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
{
    $vname = 'vrble' . ($c+1);
    $$vname = $data[$c][1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an iterator variable prior to entering the while loop:

```
$i = 0;
```

... then inside the while loop, do this:

```
list(${'vrble'.++$i}, ${'vrble'.++$i}) = $data;
```

(assuming that you'll always have 2 columns per row. See the [manual on list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) for more info.

Comment: Sounds like it could work, but I don't quite understand how to implement it inside my code. Can you please post the entire code? That would be helpful. Thx!

Comment: Just add `$i = 0;` right after `$row = 0;` and the other line after the `while` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$arr = array();
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $arr[$c] = $data[$c];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```